# Beginner - Why is my render grey?

Tags: rendering

I'm using Blender 2.8 on Windows.

So I finished animation and hit render animation and it was fine
but when I took that animated file to add sounds using a blender video editor
it always comes out as a grey gradient image, and sometimes even half of the whole
video.

I had it set to Eevee all the others like Render and Viewpoint I've tried every combination!
Set to FFmpeg and AudioAac

I have no idea what could cause this!!!!!!!

Comment: Have you tried any encoder like this - https://www.winxdvd.com/hd-video-converter-deluxe/ as I have also suffered from the same type of issues and found that, using these encoders sometimes solves my problem. or if you render your image sequence in png or any image sequence  Have you tried it rendering in an image sequence like .png or.exr sequence.